# numpy with a list of Dict: Syntax to filter elements?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy list with each elements a Dict

```
data = [
    {
        'Account' : '111',
        'RIC' : 'AAPL.OQ',
        'Position' : 100,
        'isActive' : True,
        'Rating' : math.nan
    },
    {
        'Account' : '111',
        'RIC' : 'MSFT.OQ',
        'Position' : 200,
        'isActive' : False,
        'Rating' : 73
    },
    {
        'Account' : '111',
        'RIC' : 'IBM.N',
        'Position' : 300,
        'isActive' : True,
        'Rating' : math.inf
    },

    {
        'Account' : '222',
        'RIC' : 'AAPL.OQ',
        'Position' : 1000,
        'isActive' : False,
        'Rating' : 89
    },
    {
        'Account' : '222',
        'RIC' : 'MSFT.OQ',
        'Position' : 2000,
        'isActive' : True,
        'Rating' : np.nan
    },
    {
        'Account' : '222',
        'RIC' : 'IBM.N',
        'Position' : 3000,
        'isActive' : True,
        'Rating' : 59
    }
]
data = np.array(data)
```

How do I filter for example only return elements where isActive==True?

Unlike pandas, numpy don't support syntax like data[data.isActive==True]

I am looking for numpy syntax, and **not** look for a solution where you convert above 'data' to  simple python list (then try list comprehension) or convert to pandas.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this?   `numpy` is simply not oriented towards mixed data like this.  You're battling the tool.  Why not use a tool that IS designed for it, like list-of-dicts or pandas, or even sqlite?

Comment: I know how to do with list comprehension or use pandas. I just want to know if this can be done (or not) with numpy. I am not trying to battle the tools. I just want to know "No such thing let you do this easily with numpy"

Comment: Look into https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html Though to be honest it seems a bit clunky (and less efficient) for your usecase. Python list comprehensions have a lot of syntax sugar that suit filtering and manipulation the way you seem to be wanting it

Comment: That's an object dtype array.  For all practical purposes, that's a list.  Making it an array adds nothing..

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment you can use a record array. Still numpy might not be the right tool.

```py
rec = np.core.records.fromrecords(
    [tuple(d.values()) for d in data],
    names=list(data[0].keys()),
    formats=[np.dtype("<U16"), np.dtype("<U16"), int, bool, float],
)
```

```py
>>> rec[rec.isActive == True]
rec.array([('111', 'AAPL.OQ',  100,  True, nan),
           ('111', 'IBM.N',  300,  True, inf),
           ('222', 'MSFT.OQ', 2000,  True, nan),
           ('222', 'IBM.N', 3000,  True, 59.)],
          dtype=[('Account', '<U16'), ('RIC', '<U16'), ('Position', '<i8'), ('isActive', '?'), ('Rating', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is `object` dtype:

```
In [239]: arr
Out[239]: 
array([{'Account': '111', 'RIC': 'AAPL.OQ', 'Position': 100, 'isActive': True, 'Rating': nan},
       {'Account': '111', 'RIC': 'MSFT.OQ', 'Position': 200, 'isActive': False, 'Rating': 73},
       {'Account': '111', 'RIC': 'IBM.N', 'Position': 300, 'isActive': True, 'Rating': inf},
       {'Account': '222', 'RIC': 'AAPL.OQ', 'Position': 1000, 'isActive': False, 'Rating': 89},
       {'Account': '222', 'RIC': 'MSFT.OQ', 'Position': 2000, 'isActive': True, 'Rating': nan},
       {'Account': '222', 'RIC': 'IBM.N', 'Position': 3000, 'isActive': True, 'Rating': 59}],
      dtype=object)
```

In such an array, each element is a reference to python object, in this case, dicts.  That's the same data layout as for a list, and access is basically same (but a bit slower):

A list comprehension:

```
In [240]: [a['isActive'] for a in arr]
Out[240]: [True, False, True, False, True, True]
```

and we can get indices for `nonzero` (or another list comprehension):

```
In [241]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[241]: (array([0, 2, 4, 5]),)
```

We can also construct a "vectorized" function to do this selection:

```
In [247]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.__getitem__('isActive'),1,1)(arr)
Out[247]: array([True, False, True, False, True, True], dtype=object)
```

For small arrays, list comprehension is faster; for large ones the `frompyfunc` approach may have a minor scaling advantage.

`pandas` constructs a separate array, Series/column,  for each dict key, and allows selection by column names.

Getting the indices directly:

```
In [251]: [i for i,v in enumerate(arr) if v['isActive']]
Out[251]: [0, 2, 4, 5]
```